# How to search for one file in Marklogic

Tags: php, xquery, marklogic

I am using *file_get_contents()* to dynamically retrieve specific file contents from my Marklogic database.

The issue that I am having is that my XML files are stored within sub-folders in the database. My exact query is currently pointing to an exact folder.

```
$test = file_get_contents('http://test:test@test.co.uk/v1/documents?uri=/contentE:/test_xml/test/23/' . $filename. '.xml');
```

How can I write my query as to something similar below that will search all folders and sub-folders for the value in *$filename*?.

```
$test = file_get_contents('http://test:test@test.co.uk/v1/documents?uri=' . $filename. '.xml');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a few more alternatives if you have control over the ingestion of the documents. For instance, you could simply truncate the directory from the document URIs. That would require the filenames to be unique though.

You could also use the filename as collection, and pass a collection parameter with the filename to /v1/search. You can tweak search to return snippets, metadata, but also the entire document.

The /v1/keyvalue approach mentioned by Joe works good as well, and you can achieve the same with /v1/search as well, with a search constraint on the element or attribute containing the filename. Instead of inserting that in the document itself, you can also put it in document properties.

HTH!

Comment: Removing the directories seemed to be the simplest option to take and have reloaded the entire database to delete the {path} from the database.

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in mechanism in the REST API to retrieve a document from any directory based on it's "filename". MarkLogic doesn't actually have a notion of "filename"; document URIs are opaque.

There is a mechanism in XQuery to accomplish what you want. You can enable the URI lexicon, and search for URIs that match a substring, using [`cts:uri-match()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uri-match):

```
cts:uri-match("*" || $filename || ".xml")
```

If you need this functionality exposed through the REST API, you can create an [extension module](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_41710).

If this is a common access pattern for your application, you should consider inserting the filename into an element or attribute in your documents. Doing so would make this type of query much more performant (not having to do a substring match), and give you greater flexibility when it comes to access patterns (for instance, the REST API built-in [`/keyvalue` endpoint](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_82833)).